# Java and JSP - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, getter-setter

How can I set property and get it on a jsp page?

my Hello.class,

```
package Foo;

public class Hello
{
    private String message;

    public String sayHello ()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String x) {
        this.message = x;
    }
}
```

My index.jsp,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom Class</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%@ page import="Foo.Hello" %>

    <%
    Hello hello = new Hello();

    hello.setMessage("Hello There!");
    out.print(hello.getMessage());
    out.print(hello.sayHello());
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

Error,

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /custom-class/index.jsp at line 12

9:     <%
10:     Hello hello = new Hello();
11: 
12:     hello.setMessage("Hello There!");
13:     out.print(hello.getMessage());
14:     out.print(hello.sayHello());
15:     %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Foo.Hello.setMessage(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:908)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:837)
    org.apache.jsp.custom_002dclass.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Foo.Hello.setMessage(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    org.apache.jsp.custom_002dclass.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I'm new to Java and JSP. What have done incorrectly?

Comment: What all jars you have included?

Comment: @teelou Java libraries `*.jar` files.

Comment: what do they to do with this?

Comment: probably the previous version of your `Hello` .class file (without `setMessage` method) was not replaced by the new version of .class (with `setMessage` method). so there is a class but there's no method body. try to clean the project.

Comment: @mangusta that now makes sense. so what should i do to get the new Hello?

Comment: close your server,clean project and redeploy your project again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It now works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find any problem in your code it is working fine i think you have to clean your project and redeploy it on your server and also clean and restart your server then it will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

For people who encounter this problem in the future:

I just had the same problem and I **removed tomcat server** from "IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Application Servers" and I **added it again**. and it works fine now.